# Selectively exracting files from tar.gz file

Tags: tar, compression, unzip

I have a file data_backup_202.tar.gz whcih contains more than 400 files. Datestamp of those files goes back to 2010.

I want to extract or decompress files for last 6months from this data_backup_202.tar.gz.

Answer (score 1):

List the contents with `tar tzf data_backup_202.tar.gz | cat --number`.

Use `tail` to chop the list to include only the members you want to extract:

```
tar tzf data_backup_202.tar.gz | \
  tail -n 256
```

Pipe the list of desired member names through `xargs` which will put as many member names on the generated command line as it can, while avoiding "`Line too long`" errors:

```
tar tzf data_backup_202.tar.gz | \
  tail -n 256 | \
  xargs -r tar xvf data_backup_202.tar.gz
```

Read `man xargs tail tar`.